# Core Data One-To-Many Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, relationship

The question i have is in regards to a `Core Data` `one-to-many relationship` as of right now i have my app being able to let the user input employee information and saving to `core data`, then updating the `employee` table view. The problem i face is the relationship between the `employee` and delivery. Im currently trying to display a specific employees deliveries when clicking on an `employee` in the `employee` table view. After selecting an employee from the employee tableView i want it to segue to another tableview and display the employees deliveries in another `UITableview`.

What I'm trying to Accomplish:

```
1) Display Specific Employee's Deliveries

2) Add deliveries to the NSSet
```

Here are my two `managedObjects`

```
extension Delievery {

    @NSManaged var address: String?
    @NSManaged var phoneNumber: String?
    @NSManaged var subTotal: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var total: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var employee: Employee?

}

extension Employee {

    @NSManaged var first: String?
    @NSManaged var last: String?
    @NSManaged var phoneNumber: String?
    @NSManaged var wage: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var delievery: NSSet?

}
```

how i prepared for segue from `employeeTableViewController` to `deliveryTableViewContorller`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue == "DelieverySegue"{
        let employeeDeliveries = segue.destinationViewController as! DelieveryTableViewController



        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow



        let selectedEmployee = employees[indexPath!.row]

        employeeDeliveries.employee = selectedEmployee





    }
}
```

The variables of the deliveryTableViewController are

```
var employee: NSManagedObject!


var deliveries : [NSManagedObject]!


var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext!
```

In this photo it shows the rest of my `deliveryTableViewController` the problem i have is how do i return the amount of deliveries for a specific employee in the `numberOfRowsInSection` function and how do i fetch the deliveries of the employee.
[deliveryTableViewController set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r05o.png)

In this last photo my question is how to i add this delivery entry to the employee selected? this is how I'm currently saving my delivery entries
[how i save my delivery entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOqQv.png)

If you made it this far i appreciate you looking through my problem. If anyone can help me the slightest with this issue i'd appreciate it if you feel i've left some information out that is needed please let me know.

UPDATE:

Here is the picture of the DelieveryTableViewController (yes i know i spelt delivery wrong)

[image: Picture of DelieveryTableViewController with viewDidLoad()]

also need to set the NSPredicate

[image: Picture of DeliveryTableViewController fetchRequest function]

this is home I'm preparing for segue in EmployeeTableViewController

[image]

these are my variables for EmployeeTableViewController

[image]

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? I can see that you have spelled your extension 'Delievery' instead of 'Delivery' and this is true for a few other things like the segue ID and your 'DelieveryTableViewController', etc. While these mistakes might cancel each other out, if you spelled it consistently it would definitely rule it out as a source of errors. What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @fizzy Updated my answer.

Comment: Code in screenshots is annoying. Please paste code as text.

Comment: Sorry about that, will do when submitting new questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setting the relationship**

With one to many relationships, it is easiest to set the to-one relationship:

```
delivery.employee = employee
```

Put this line in your `completeOrder` method (you may need to pass the `employee` reference from a previous VC).  CoreData will automatically set the inverse relationship for you, adding `delivery` to the `deliveries` set for the `employee`.

**Showing the Deliveries in a Table View**

Having set the relationship, the `deliveries` property of `employee` contains a set of `Delivery` objects to which it is related.  To display these in a table view, create your `deliveries` array from this set (eg. in `viewDidLoad`):

```
deliveries = employee.delivery.allObjects()
```

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` can then just use `deliveries.count` and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can use `deliveries[indexPath.row]` to determine which `Delivery` to display in each cell.

(An alternative is to fetch the `deliveries` array in the normal way, but to use a predicate to restrict the results to those that are related to your `employee`:

```
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"employee == %@", employee)
```

Longer term, you should consider using `NSFetchedResultsController` which is designed for displaying CoreData objects in table view.)

**Update**

You don't need the `thisEmployee` variable.  Just change the `Employee` variable to be `Employee` class:

```
var employee : Employee!
```

Then you should be able to set

```
deliveries = employee.deliveries?.allObjects as! [NSManagedObject]
```

And in your `fetchDelivery()` method, set the predicate with

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"employee == %@", employee)
```

(after `let fetchRequest = ....`).

**Update 2**

It's difficult to see where the nil value is.  To track it down, try printing the value of `employee` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `DelieveryTableViewController`.  If it's nil, there is a problem with passing the value in `prepareForSegue`.  If not, print `employee.deliveries`, etc.  Post your results.

Comment: Thank you so much, this isn't really a complicated app.. I'm just starting to learn Core Data and i do agree the NSFetchedResultsController is a lot better.. Thank you again

Comment: hey pbasdf i have one more quick question regarding Showing Deliveries in a Table View.... when trying to do deliveries = employee.delivery.allObjects() its give me an error saying that i cannot assign a AnyObject to a NSMangedObject any way i can fix this? heres the code: this is what i put in the viewDidLoad

Comment: let description = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Delievery", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        
        var delivery = Delievery(entity: (description)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        let employeeDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Employee", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        
        let thisEmployee = Employee(entity: (employeeDescription)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
      
        
        delivery = thisEmployee.delievery?.allObjects

Comment: You just need to "cast" the array correctly: `deliveries = employee.delivery.allObjects() as! [NSManagedObject]`

Comment: okay thanks a lot I'm sorry I'm new to iOS and swift and since i have a variable called employee : NSMangedObject! but to directly get at it i have use the NSEntityDescription.entityForName and insertIntoManagedObjectContext: correct or am i doing this wrong?

Comment: That will create a new `Employee` - is that what you want?  I thought you were passing the `employee` reference from a previous view controller - as you do in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: yes i am, you are correct it keeps adding another employee, but i can't do employee.delivery.allObjects() because its of type NSMangedObject do i need to cast that as something as well? cause now when i segue between each tableViewController it adds employee which is not what i want.

Comment: Can you edit your post above and put your current code at the bottom; and I'll update my answer accordingly - lengthy discussion in comments is discouraged.

Comment: this doesn't work cause I'm sending from the EmployeeTableViewController a NSManagedObject. When i cast it in the prepareForeSegue in the EmployeeTableViewController as a Employee like this employeeDeliveries.employee = selectedEmployee as! Employee it gives me the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when executing the code deliveries = employee.deliveries?.allObjects as! [NSManagedObject]... I'm sorry for making this so difficult Core Data is extremely hard concept for me to understand

Comment: here ill upload the EmployeeTableViewController and show you how I'm sending it... and its variables

Comment: okok i updated my question just letting you know, displaying pictures of my EmployeeTableViewController.. i can't thank you enough for all the help

Comment: I know you said you were tied up doing something but any chance you got to take a look what i updated? @pbasdf

Comment: Sorry, @fizzy, I have only just come back to your question.  I see you have raised another question directly relating to the "unexpectedly found nil"; I don't have much to add to Marcus's answer and comments there.

Comment: I'm doing what marcus as suggested and see if i can get it working i appreciate all the help you both have given me @pbsasdf