# Core Data fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, fatal-error

Currently getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when executing this line of code `deliveries = employee.delievery?.allObjects as! [NSManagedObject]`

I'm currently sending an employee from another `tableView` like this `var employees : [NSManagedObject]!` and `prepareForSegue` like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue == "DelieverySegue"{
        let employeeDeliveries = segue.destinationViewController as! DelieveryTableViewController



        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow



        let selectedEmployee = employees[indexPath!.row] as! Employee

        employeeDeliveries.employee = selectedEmployee





    }
}
```

The reason why i `prepareForSegue` like this is because the `tableView` I'm segueing to has  a variable `var employee: Employee!`

Once i go to segue it crashes at this line of code in my `DeliveryTableViewController` in the `viewDidLoad()`

`deliveries = employee.delievery?.allObjects as! [NSManagedObject]`

What my `NSManagedObject` looks like for both.

`extension Employee {`

```
@NSManaged var first: String?
@NSManaged var last: String?
@NSManaged var phoneNumber: String?
@NSManaged var wage: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var delievery: NSSet?
```

`}`

`extension Delivery {`

```
@NSManaged var address: String?
@NSManaged var phoneNumber: String?
@NSManaged var subTotal: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var total: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var employee: Employee?
```

`}`

and this is how I'm setting the relationship in my other `viewController` that creates a new delivery

`@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {`

```
    let description = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Employee", inManagedObjectContext: manageObjectContext)


    let employee = Employee(entity: (description)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: manageObjectContext)
    employee.first = first.text
    employee.last = last.text
    employee.phoneNumber = phoneNumber.text
    employee.wage = Float(wage.text!)
    employee.id = Int(employeeId.text!)


    do{
        try
        manageObjectContext.save()
        first.text = ""
        last.text = ""
        phoneNumber.text = ""
        wage.text = ""
        employeeId.text = ""
        status.text = "Success!"



    }catch let error as NSError{

        status.text = error.localizedFailureReason
    }
```

`}`

am i casting it wrong?.. i have established a relationship between Employee and Delivery already. I'm currently trying to display the deliveries of the employee i am sending when clicking on a specific employee in the `EmployeeTableViewController` any help regarding this would be extremely helpful thank you for your time.

What i get at run time, it fails after segueing to `DeliveryTableViewController`

[image: What i get after segueing to DeliveryTableViewController]

Comment: Dont cast it or use [Delivery] as obj. Also check for value existing using if let or guard before proceding.

Comment: Why dont you declare as employee.delievery?.allObjects as! [Delievert_entity] ???

Comment: well i have a variable in my `DeliveryTableViewController` called `var deliveries : [NSManagedObject]!` could i do ` deliveries = employee.delievery?.allObjects as! [Delievery]` ?  @SandeepBhandari

Comment: fizzy : Yes you can if you declare var deliveries : [Delievery]! I believe :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari the follow did not work

Comment: @SandeepBhandari  i have  a pervious question thats display more information regarding my code at this link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806731/core-data-one-to-many-swift?noredirect=1#comment61230289_36806731) it shows the set up of my code

Comment: @fizzy :is it still crashing buddy ?? It will be easy to suggest solution if you can post the crash log buddy :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes it crashed with the sam error i have gotta please not that deliveries is `var deliveries: [NSManagedObject]!`

Comment: You sure that you have deliveries for the employee selected in your db?? Or is the relation ship actually getting set ?? Can you check the sqlite file and confirm employee and delivery entries are related ???

Comment: The relationship is being set I'm sure of it in another `viewController` when creating a new delivery @SandeepBhandari ill update my question to show you

Comment: check out my update and let me know if it gives your greater insight on my problem... @SandeepBhandari

Comment: @fizzy Also, check your spelling; it's "delivery", not "delievery"; you've got it right in some places and not others. Inconsistent spelling in code is a sign that you're rushing things and being careless… and that means bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the source of your issue is undetermined by what code you have, your coding *style* is part of the problem:

```
deliveries = employee.delievery?.allObjects as! [NSManagedObject]
```

Is a VERY unsafe way to write Swift code and gives you no answers when things go wrong.  Instead, consider writing it like this:

```
guard let delievery = employee.delivevery else {
  print("Employee: \(employee)")
  fatalError("No deliver object referenced by employee")
}
guard let deliveries = delievery.allObjects as? [NSManagedObject] else {
  fatalError("Unexpected class type in allObjects")
}
```

With this change you can see if you don't have a `delievery` object or if there is an issue with your call to `allObjects`.

Continuing with this, why are you calling allObjects?  `Employee` has a relationship to `Delivery` which is called `delievery`.  This means that it returns an `NSSet`.  Why call `allObjects` at all?  That is just going to turn it into an Array which is just another flavor of a collection.

In any event, force downcasting in Swift is **BAD** and should be avoided unless you know absolutely without a doubt that you will get an object back every single time.  In this situation, you do not have that guarantee and should either be using an `if let` or `guard let` to confirm what you are getting.

> hey Marcus I'm gonna up load a picture of what happens when i select an employee and segue over to my `DeliveryTableViewController`

Ok, this is showing that even the employee can be nil and is unexpectedly nil.  I am guessing you have an instance variable like this:

```
var employee: Employee!
```

Again, this is a bad habit in Swift.  You should write it as a proper optional:

```
var employee: Employee?
```

Then unwrap it when you need it:

```
guard let empl = employee else {
  fatalError("Employee not set")
}
guard let delievery = empl.delivevery else {
  print("Employee: \(employee)")
  fatalError("No deliver object referenced by employee")
}
deliveries = delievery
```

And now you will have a properly unwrapped collection of `Delivery` objects assigned to your instance variable and you can display them from there.

### `NSFetchedResultsController`

Having said all of that, you should not be displaying the deliveries like this.  You really should be using an `NSFetchedResultsController` instead.  Something like this:

```
guard let emp = employee else {
    fatalError("Employee not assigned")
}
let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Delivery")
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "employee == %@", emp)

let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetch, context: emp.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

//Finish implementing the NSFetchedResultsController
```

Then use the `NSFetchedResultsController` to display the deliveries in your `UITableView`.

> makes sense so how would i do so if you look above in my EmployeeTableViewController `prepareForSegue` thats obviously not correct.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { 
        fatalError("Segue without an identifier")
    }
    switch identifier {
    case "DelieverySegue":
        guard let employeeDeliveries = segue.destinationViewController as? DelieveryTableViewController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected view controller class")
        }
        guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
            fatalError("No row selected")
        }
        let employee = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        //Use a NSFetchedResultsController here also
        //let selectedEmployee = employees[indexPath!.row] as! Employee
        employeeDeliveries.employee = employee
    default: break
    }
}
```

Again, I would be using an `NSFetchedResultsController` here as well instead of an array.  This is what the `NSFetchedResultsController` is designed for.

However, you can still use your array if you choose.  I would not recommend it.

The error here is that you are treating `segue` as a `String` when it is not.  You must extract the `identifier` from `UIStoryboardSegue` object and then compare that against the identifier you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me... i implemented the code you suggested and it crashes with the same error. "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" what do you suggest i do?

Comment: Then it is not that line of code.  Do you have an exception breakpoint turned on?  If so, what line of code is it breaking on?  If not, turn it on and restart the app :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: hey Marcus I'm gonna up load a picture of what happens when i select an employee and segue over to my `DeliveryTableViewController`

Comment: See my update.  Assuming you then see "Employee not set" when you run that tells you that you are not passing the `Empoyee` into this view controller.

Comment: makes sense so how would i do so if you look above in my `EmployeeTableViewController` ` prepareForSegue` thats obviously not correct.

Comment: hey just wanted to let you know marcus i fixed it and switched over to using the `NSFetchedResultsController` you have been a big help and i can't thank you enough i appreciate you taking out the time to figure out my problem